# React one state data automatically changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  handleSearch = (ev, index) => {
    const { dropdown_datas, dropdown_datas_search } = this.state;
    const keys = Object.keys(dropdown_datas_search);
    const current_key = keys[index];
    let value = ev.target.value;
    let current_dropdown_data = dropdown_datas_search[current_key];
    const filtered_data = current_dropdown_data.filter(robots => {
      return robots.label.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
    })

    dropdown_datas[current_key] = filtered_data
    this.setState({
      dropdown_datas: dropdown_datas
    })

  }
```

I am using this function in react.
"dropdown_datas_search" data is coming from state which data i don't wants change.
But, when i am doing the filter "dropdown_datas_search" is also changing from state.
I wants to only change and filter "current_dropdown_data" data .

Please take a look.
How can i prevent doing this.

Comment: you need to clone the object, otherwise, the same object will be referened

Comment: How to clone the objects ?

Comment: use ... operator

Comment: Can you try using this `let current_dropdown_data = Object.assign({}, dropdown_datas_search[current_key]);`?

Comment: No, It is not  working